# FQL public query returns partial data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to query the [review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/review/) table with FQL using the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

This query searches for all the reviews published for [CozyCaterers](https://www.facebook.com/cozycaterers), a business page with 24 reviews:

```
SELECT review_id, rating, message, reviewer_id FROM review where reviewee_id='492378670299'
```

Unfortunately, **it only returns two reviews out of the 24**.

PS - the review table's documentation states that "To read a review, you do not need an access token", which AFAIK means it's public data.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referencing the wrong table. Reviews are for apps (as the docs state, "A review of an application...", not pages afaik.

Try the Graph API endpoint for Page ratings (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/) instead:

```
GET /{page-id}/ratings
```

Notice that you need a Page Access Token of the respective Page to be able to query this endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to read page reviews for pages where I'm not the owner. Any idea how to do that?